# Android ListView, static item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listadapter

I have a list populated by a list adapter with data from the server. 
Regardless of the data returned (or lack thereof) I want the first item of the list to always be the same (an item I created).

How do I call the setData method so that the first item is always there?

Comment: are you searching for listview.setSelection(index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could copy the dynamic data to a local `List` and insert the static item at the beginning of the `List` each time, and then use that `List`, containing both static and dynamic data, with an `ArrayAdapter`.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Could I do this with items that are of different type? (But say, both extend the same class?)

Comment: If they both inherit from the same class, then yes, just set the `ArrayList` type to the common parent class, that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this method:

ListView lv = (initialize your list view here)

lv.addHeaderView(View v);  v is a parameter, inflate the item you always want there and put it in this way. It will always show up at the top of the list.